# Bash: Uncommenting XML tag using sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, xml-parsing

I current have a file with the following:

```
<refrigerator>
    <food="watermelon" location="topShelf" />
    <!--
    <food="mango" location="bottomShelf" />
    --> 
    <!--
    <food="orange" location="middleShelf" />
    --> 
</refrigerator>
```

How can I use 'sed' to remove `<!--` and `-->` so "mango" can be uncommented from the file? However, if there are other lines commented in the file, I want them to remain commented?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed` you could try:

```
sed '/<!--/{ N; N; s/.*\n\(.*food="mango".*\)\n.*-->.*/\1/; }' file
```

Comment: I always have so much trouble with `sed`. Can you explain how to read/interpret the line you've written? Thanks!

Comment: In particular, why don't we have to match the ending `-->`?

Comment: `/<!--/` : if the first part of a comment is found, then read the next two lines into the line buffer ( `N` ) . Then the substute command ( `s` ) replaces the three lines with the middle line ( `\1` ) if it contains the phrase `food="mango"`. If the middle line does not contain the phrase, there is not substitution and the the three lines in the line buffer get printed.

Comment: Yes you could probably further improve the reliability by including `-->`. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 5):

`sed` is not the right tool for this (not multi-line by default), try using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), this is more suitable for this case :

```
$ perl -i -0777 -pe 's/\s*<!--\s*\n(.*?food="mango".*?)\n\s*-->/\n$1/' file.txt
```

### Output

```
<refrigerator>
    <food="watermelon" location="topShelf" />
    <food="mango" location="bottomShelf" /> 
    <!--
    <food="orange" location="middleShelf" />
    --> 
</refrigerator>
```

### Explanations

- `-i` switch edit the file *in place* (just like `sed -i`)
- `-0777` read the whole file in one time (can read by *paragraph* too with `-00`)
- `-p` assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program, and print newlines
- `s///` is the skeleton for `sed` like substitutions
- `\s` is a blank character for Perl
- `.*?` stands for *not greedy* match
- `$1` is the same as sed `\1` (*captured* part)

### Doc

See

- `perl -h`
- [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Comment: I'm currently limited to using bash. If `sed` is not the right tool, is it possible with `awk`? Thanks for the response!

Comment: This is a shell command as you had seen I guess. If you don't have perl, you can use Scrutinizer's solution with `sed`, but it will be harder to re-use in the future I guess. Sed is not made originally for multilines.

Comment: @user459811, Since you run Ubuntu, `perl` will be there, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I created using `awk`

Identifying the required `xml` element having "Connector server=" inside the element, but not at the first line that has `<!--`

#### script.awk:

```
/<!--/ && /-->/ {print;next;}
/-->/ && insideComment {
    if (insideDesiredElement) {
        sub("<!--","",firstLine);
        sub("-->","");
        insideDesiredElement = 0;
    }
    print firstLine ORS commentBlock $0;
    insideComment = 0;
    next;
}
/<!--/ {
    insideComment = 1;
    commentBlock = "";
    firstLine = $0;
    next;
}
insideComment {
    if ($0 ~ "Connector server=") insideDesiredElement = 1;
    commentBlock = commentBlock $0 ORS;
    next;
}1
```

#### running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.xml
```